# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument when setting up a working directory

Tags: r

I am setting up my working directory to run a differential expression code on R. I keep getting this error, Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

I have tried changing the directory with `setwd` but that has not worked

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ballgown")
library(ballgown)
install.packages("calibrate")
library(calibrate)

##specify data directory and make ballgown object##
###directory files must look EXACTLY like the files in the example ballgown extdata directory###
data_directory=file.path("user/cash/Desktop/ccar-1 differential expression analysis/differential expresison")
data_directory
bg=ballgown(dataDir=data_directory, samplePattern='IKH', meas='all')
meas = 
###[ballgown instance with 227079 transcripts and 12 samples]###
View(bg)
sampleNames(bg)
```

Error message is

> Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument